# Extending jw_watermarks in typo3 fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid

Sry in advance, new here.
I need to generate watermarks on every image with jw_watermarks ext.

With the following code the original image gets involved - everything is fine:

```
                    <a title="{file.title}" data-description="{file.description}" href="{jw:watermark(watermarkSrc: '/fileadmin/Watermark.png', watermarkOpacity: '1', watermarkBackgroundColor: 'FFFFFF', watermarkBackgroundOpacity: '0', watermarkOffset: 0, watermarkPositionVertical: 'bottom', src: file.uid, treatIdAsReference: 1, width: settings.media.popup.width, height: settings.media.popup.height)}">
                    <f:render partial="Media/Rendering/Image" arguments="{file: file, dimensions: dimensions, settings: settings}" />
                    </a>
```

But I need to extend the  jw_watermarks ext. to all generated images. Tried to work on the media-ViewHelper by extending the srcset, but I am not able to adapt the viewhelper to all generated images.

```
<f:media
class="img-responsive"
file="{file}"
width="{dimensions.width}"
height="{dimensions.height}"
alt="{file.alternative}"
title="{file.title}"
additionalAttributes="{srcset: '{f:uri.image(image: file, maxWidth: 768)} 768w,
                                {f:uri.image(image: file, maxWidth: 990)} 990w,
                                {f:uri.image(image: file, maxWidth: 1200)} 1200w,
                                {f:uri.image(image: file, maxWidth: 1440)} 1440w,
                                {f:uri.image(image: file, maxWidth: 1900)} 1900w',
                       sizes: '(min-width: 1200px) 50vw, 100vw'}"
```

/>

Comment: I don't have an answer but addresses it to the extension owner: https://github.com/JW301/jw_watermark/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

The docs are saying:

> The viewhelper can be used like the f:uri.image ViewHelper.
>
> The following additional arguments can be used to add the watermark:
>
> - watermarkSrc
> - watermarkTreatIdAsReference
> - watermarkImage

So, it should work by simply replacing `{f:uri.image(image: file, maxWidth: 768)}` by `{jw:watermark(watermarkSrc: '/fileadmin/Watermark.png', watermarkOpacity: '1', watermarkBackgroundColor: 'FFFFFF', watermarkBackgroundOpacity: '0', watermarkOffset: 0, watermarkPositionVertical: 'bottom', image: file, maxWidth: 768)}` and so on.

Comment: By replacing I got this,
"Oops, an error occurred!
The argument "additionalAttributes" was registered with type "array", but is of type "string" in view helper "TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\MediaViewHelper"." And when i look into the source code, I see the not rendered Code:

Comment: Did you remember to escape the quotation marks? The `srcset` has already started the single quotes - the parser gets confused...